# kdump fails when /etc/kdump.conf points /dev/sdx and path /

Tags: linux

I try to get vmcore editting /etc/kdump.conf on RHEL6.5 or CentOS.
/etc/fstab is set

/dev/sda7 /dump

ext4 /dev/sda7
path /

When I issue commands below, it does not emit vmcore at all.

echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger

Strange thing is, when I edit /etc/fstab,

UUID=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX /dump

System emits vmcore.

Why? and how can I get vmcore with the lines,

ext4 /dev/sda7
path /

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When executing

```
# service kdump restart
```

kdump regenerates initrd.img.
I unpacked initrd.img and found that command "findfs" is related to this matter.
man findfs tells that only UUID or LABEL needs to be offerd as an argument.

So, the answer is, you can't use device-name in /etc/kdump.conf.

Thanks.